# ng-model as link inside input text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to convert my ng-model to a link.
I have an input binding a value. This value is a link.

Basically, I want to when you click on the text in the input (on not when you click on the textbox), it opens a link.

Here what I am trying to do:
html :

```
<input name="mytext"type="text" ng-model="field.savedValue" />
```

js:

```
field.savedValue = "&lt;a href=&quot;" + $scope.baseUrl + "?etn=" + field.Values[0] + "&amp;pagetype=entityrecord&amp;id=" + field.lookupGuid + "&quot;&gt;" + field.value + "&lt;&frasl;a&gt;";
```

but in this case, it just display me the whole content as a string (can't click on it...).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: That's the way a text input works it's a **text** input not a html input

Comment: I know, that's why I ask how I could convert the text to a html link.

Comment: how can one click on the text in the input WITHOUT clicking the textbox ? The event will bubble anyways

Comment: I don't know, that's why I ask :) I work with CRM, I am creating a custom lookup field. In CRM, on lookup, if you click on the text, it opens a link, if you click on the textbox (where there is no text), you can edit the content. I would like to reproduce the same thing.